# Rolling A Die Question

Tags: probability, solution-verification

When we roll a single six-sided die, what is the probability of rolling 3 even and 1 odd number?

I want to solve this using $P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|}$ where $|E|$ is the event space, and $|S|$ is the sample space.

I can get the sample space: $|S| = 6^4$ because we are dealing with a six-sided die being rolled four times.

But how do you get the event space for this? I know getting an even number of one roll is $\frac{1}{2}$ and same with an odd, but would it maybe be $3^4 + 1^4$ because we want three even numbers and one odd number?

Comment: There are $3^4$ ways to roll "even, even, even, odd" in that order. There are also $3^4$ ways to roll "even, odd, even, even". Cover the other cases and sum up the possibilities to get $|E|$.

Comment: So there is $4!$ ways to get this then? Lets say $3^4 \cdot 4!$?

Comment: @E__ Don't just throw factorial signs around willy-nilly... stop and think about what the factorial sign represents.  No, there are only $4$ ways to choose the order of the parities of the numbers.  Those four ways are: `EEEO`, `EEOE`, `EOEE` and `OEEE`.  There aren't $24=4!$ ways.  Note that the `E`'s in the above are indistinguishable from one another.

Comment: Even more generally, when rolling $n$ dice and $k$ of them are even, there would be $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to pick the order of the parities of the numbers.  Here, $\binom{4}{3}=\binom{4}{1}=4$

Comment: As an aside... while yes, we could have used counting principles and looked at each of the $6^4$ distinct outcomes where we kept track not only of the parity of each face rolled, but the *number* on the face as well... this is unnecessary.  This question is *identical* in all but flavor to that of flipping a fair coin four times and asking for three heads.  You could have solved this with less arithmetic using the binomial distribution and noting that even occurs half of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In how many ways can you put the $1$ odd die? $4$

In how many ways can you choose a even number in one trial? $3$ ( in three,instead?)

In how many ways can you choose a odd number in one trial? $3$

So the probability is $\frac{4\cdot 3^4}{6^4} = \frac{1}{4}  $

In these cases, one good way to think it's to build a 'mental tree' of the sample space and to distinguish the branches in the event space.

Comment: I counted multiplying by $4$ I think

Comment: @AnayAggarwal He/she makes the distinction.

Comment: @AnayAggarwal Yes, the even number are member of one group, say "even". So we don´t distinguish in between that group. The distinction is between "even" and "odd" only.